# USB 3.0 hub(s) connect as USB 2.0 devices (and consequentially their downstream devices)

Tags: usb

I have an application where I have multiple USB 3.0 devices (cameras) that need to connect to a single USB 3.0 port.  I've got some other external criteria (ESD protection, external power supply, etc) that has limited my hub options to a few industrial hubs.

While testing the hubs, I have found 3 that connect as USB 2.0 devices instead of USB 3.0, and are otherwise fully functional.  I have verified the issue is not cabling and is independent of the USB hub chipsets (seen on both GL3520 and VLI VL812).   The run between the motherboard and the chipset is very short ( < 2.0m).

My knowledge of USB is limited, but I assume there's some sort of negotiation that occurs when initially connecting (ex - Ethernet will auto-negotiate slower/half duplex if pairs are missing).  Can anybody explain this process and why I might be connecting at lower speeds or at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this either, but it seems like the GL3520 hub is USB 3.1 and VLI VL812 is 3.0. Maybe those cameras are only compatible with one of them? Try moving them between hubs to see it that changes anything.

Comment: Actually, I see the hubs connecting as USB 2.0 before I ever connect the cameras.  Also, I edited for clarity, but the issue presents itself on both chipsets.

Comment: Would one of the cameras show as 2.0 when connected in the port used for the hub?